# locahost work s3 upload file but server not work upload file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I tried s3 upload image_file on rails. It works on locahost3000 but does not work s3 upload image_file on real server(Digital Oceans). I'm currently getting the following error: An Excon::Error::Forbidden occurred in unit_concept_descs#create:Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden. I use CarrierWave gem for image_upload.
I do not specially understand that It works on locahost but does not work on real server.
How can I do. I spent about two weeks. Please help me.

Comment: This is a permissions issue -- the  secret key id and secret key need to be set properly.

Comment: I set properly aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key. if I set them improperly, localhost3000 does not work.